# jsonata $merge instanceof information lost

Tags: jsonata

I am constructing a TypeScript OO model from JSON using JSONata.

One of the driving factors is to have a fully typed object model representation of the JSON.

If I use `$merge([...])` when mapping from the source JSON to the object model `instanceof` information is not preserved.

Perhaps better illustrated with an example:-

Consider a registered function `myFactory` to create an instance of an object:

```
function myFactory() : Person {
  return new Person();
}
```

If I just use the factory, like this:

```
{
  person: $myFactory()
}
```

Then the `result.person instanceof Person` is `true`.

If however I use `$merge([..])` the type information is lost:

```
{
  person: $merge([$myFactory(), source.someAttributes])
}
```

Then the `result.person instanceof Person` is `false`.

This appears to be caused [here](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/blob/master/src/functions.js#L1768).

At the moment I am working around it by passing *ALL* the properties of the object to the factory function, for example:

```
function myFactory(other : any) : Person {
  return Object.assign(new Person(), other);
}
...
{
  person: $myFactory(source.someAttributes)
}
```

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I posed the question [here](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/457).

However, since it is an edge case, and can be easily worked around (by either passing all properties to the factory method or overriding the `$merge([...])` function) I feel there is nothing more to add.

My local override of the `$merge([...])` function is this, for future reference.

```
const expression: Expression = JSONata(mapping);
expression.registerFunction("merge", merge);

...

function merge(arg: any[]): any {
  if (typeof arg === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  }

  var result = Object.create(arg[0]);

  arg.forEach(function(obj: any) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      result[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```